# Want to append records in two file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, sed

**My first input file contains records name abc.txt:**

```
abc@gmail.com

bscd@yahoo.co.in

abcd.21@gmail.com

1234@hotmail.com
```

**My second file contains record name details.txt:**

```
123456^atulsample^1203320
```

**I want my final file having output to be Final.txt:**

```
abc@gmail.com^123456^atulsample^1203320

bscd@yahoo.co.in^123456^atulsample^1203320

abcd.21@gmail.com^123456^atulsample^1203320
```

I have uses sed command but I am not getting my required output.

Kindly help as I don't have much knowledge in shell scripting.

Comment: Perhaps you could share the sed command that you already tried? Then we might see what you've tried so far and what you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this;

```
#!/bin/bash
while read -r line
do
    detail="$line"
    sed '/^[ \t]*$/d' abc.txt | sed "s/$/^${detail}/" >> Final.txt
done < "details.txt"
```

this is to delete blank lines;

```
 sed '/^[ \t]*$/d' abc.txt
```

this is to append from details.txt

```
sed "s/$/^${detail}/"
```